# Eigenvalue of an Euler product type operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, quantum-mechanics

### Background

Let us have the following orthonormal basis such that:

$$ \langle m | n \rangle = \delta_{mn}$$

Consider the following operators defined as:

$$ \hat 1 = | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | + | 2 \rangle \langle 2 | + | 3 \rangle \langle 3 | + \dots $$
$$ \hat 2 = | 1 \rangle \langle 2 | + | 2 \rangle \langle 4 | + | 3 \rangle \langle 6 | + \dots $$
$$ \hat 3 = | 1 \rangle \langle 3 | + | 2 \rangle \langle 6 | + | 3 \rangle \langle 9 | + \dots $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ \hat n = | 1 \rangle \langle n | + | 2 \rangle \langle 2n | + | 3 \rangle \langle 3n | + \dots $$

Hence, we notice it these operators have the following properties:

$$ \hat a \cdot \hat b = \hat b \cdot \hat a = (\hat{ab}) $$

For example:

$$ \hat 2 \cdot \hat 2 = \hat 4 $$

We notice that it has nice multiplicative properties and hence, define the following operator:

$$ \hat H = \hat 1^s + \hat 2^s + \hat 3^s + \hat 4^s + \dots $$

Using the Euler product formula (which seems to hold in this case as well):

$$ \hat H = (\hat 1-  \hat 2^s)^{-1} \cdot (\hat 1-  \hat 3^s)^{-1} \cdot (\hat 1-  \hat5^s)^{-1} \cdot \dots    $$

### Questions

What is the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this operator $\hat H$? Can one define $H$ as some sort of Hamiltonian or density operator?

### Edit

I just thought of the following idea. What if we define the Hamiltonian as:

$$ H' =  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & H \\
   H^\dagger  & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

The above is a Hermitian operator. What would it physically correspond to?

Comment: What's the little $s$ mean? Transpose/adjoint?

Comment: It means raised to the power ... Sorry for the confusion ...

Comment: Aside from $\hat 1$, none of the operators $\hat n$ appear normal (i.e. $\hat n^\dagger\cdot\hat n\neq\hat n\cdot\hat n^\dagger$, where $\dagger$ is the adjoint).  So I would be hesitant to call $\hat H$ similar to a Hamiltonian operator, or a physical observable.  But I think this construction is interesting, and you might be able to do something else with it.  I wish you success!

Comment: @user254433 Thank you very much ... I think I managed to construct a hermitian Hamiltonian from this ... I would be interested in your thoughts

Comment: The 2x2 matrix Hamiltonian reminds me of a coupled two-state system.  Another similarity to this is that $H$ is bounded (continuous in $L^2$), which means, in particular, the eigenvalues (energies) are bounded.  This is unlike the usual unbounded operator $-\nabla^2+V$, which has arbitrarily large energies.  Also, another Hermitian operator you could try is $H+H^\dagger$.